# MySQL error in select statement inside of trigger

Tags: mysql, select, triggers

I've recently started working on MySQL n right now i want to create a trigger but MySQL is returning an error in my syntax.

```
delimiter $$;
create trigger abc after insert on ratings
for each row
    begin
        set @n1 = select avg(rating) from ratings join users where ratings.uname=users.uname 
        and ratings.bookid=new.bookid users.`type`='admin' or users.`type`='critic';
        update books set avgcriticrating = @n1 where bookid=new.bookid;
end;
```

The select statement runs perfectly when fired on its own but gives an error when i use it inside of the trigger.

Here's the error that MySQL gives

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select avg(rating) from ratings join users where ratings.uname=users.uname an' at line 4
```

Both the books and ratings table contain a field called bookid.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a single value from a select statement, the statement has to be in (brackets).

```
set @n1 = (select avg(rating) from ratings join users where ratings.uname=users.uname 
    and ratings.bookid=new.bookid users.`type`='admin' or users.`type`='critic');
```

The next error will occur at `new.bookid users` - there might be an `and` or an `or` missing.